# creating web services for iphone and cakephp project

Tags: iphone, web-services, cakephp

Is there any way to collaborate Cakephp project with Iphone. Like: retrieving json data with cakephp models as WebServices in iphone. The aim behind this question is to use the cakephp code rather then creating WebServices differently.

Your help will be appreciated, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Cakephp is  a framework that outputs json data as much as like any other php frameworks out there.
You have to write functiosn like there:

```
public function api_get_release_tracks($release_id = null) {
        if($release_id) {
            $tracks = $this->Track->find('all', array( //sql queries are better here
                    'fields' => array('id', 'name', 'duration', 'duration_str',
                        'sample_audio', 'price', 'local_price'),
                    'conditions' => array('release_id' => $release_id),
                    'order' => array('position ASC')
                ));
            $this->set('tracks', $tracks);
            $this->set('_serialize', 'tracks');
        }
    }
```

Then you can get the json output in this url:

```
http://localhost:8090/{api name in cofig}/{controller name}/{things after api_ in function name}/{input parameters}.json
```

read more in [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/rest.html)

Also you can alter the routing to change the name 
 api
to anything in

```
Configure::write('Routing.prefixes', array('master', 'api'));
```

in core.php in app/config

Comment: Thanks a lot @Gunner Aziz. I am going to implement your answer.

Comment: There is no need to create api_ prefixed actions, this will just add a massive bloat of code and probably duplicate a lot what other methods already do. Also the find() in this example should go into a model method. It would be more efficient to re-use existing controller methods and the request handler OR to have a single ApiController that will act as a dispatcher that will call model methods and return the result. Chapter 4 of the CakePHP application cookbook describes that in detail. http://www.cakedc.com/how-to-use-cakephp

Comment: I personally do not recommend to use find() while writing API's for mobile. Use $this->query('YourQuery'); instead. This uses less memory and serves query in less time.

Comment: ya,thats just an example. Serialize does the job for json and with find I get extra columns...